# Should this be considered as a class in UML class diagram or as a type?

Tags: uml, android-webview, class-diagram

I am creating the class diagram for my project. I will use some `WebViews` in a class. My question is:

Should I write the `WebView` class in my UML class diagram or can I only use a `WebView` as a type?

For example, if a have a string: `String a`, in my class diagram, I will put a `: String` in the class attributes, but if I have `WebView wv` in my class, can I do the same as for the string and write in the class attributes: `wv: WebView` or I have to write the `WebView` class and then make an association with my class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can do either.

Longer answer: UML doesn't constrain what you do here.  There is no rule that says what types can be used as the value of attributes vs. what must be shown as associations.

Longest answer is actually a question: what do you want to communicate with the diagram?  Class diagrams are good for showing structure - the links (associations) among classes.  So: is the association between your class and your Webview instance interesting?  For example, does the same instance of WebView also relate to some other object?  Is there anything about *that* relationship that's interesting?  Can the WebView instance outlive the instance of your class?  And so on.

hth.